# How to list more than 10000 swift objects in Openstack4j?

Tags: java, openstack, object-storage

The [official tutorial code](http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/objectstorage) is:

```
List<? extends SwiftObject> objs = os.objectStorage().objects().list(containerName);
```

But this has clear limit of 10000 files. Is there any more or less common approach to list larger containers?

Answer (score 0):

OK, made it myself, seems right way in accordance to testing results. Appropriate API sorts results by name (this is documented) and accounts 'name marker' which indicates the point to start list with.

```
final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

final ObjectStorageObjectService oservice = os.objectStorage().objects();
final ObjectListOptions listOptions = ObjectListOptions.create().limit(LIST_PAGE_LIMIT);
List<? extends SwiftObject> objects;
do {
    // Get next list page.
    objects = oservice.list(CONTAINER_NAME, listOptions);

    // If we have some result setup next page.
    if (!objects.isEmpty()) {
        listOptions.marker(objects.get(objects.size() - 1).getName());
    }

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("SWIFT OS: listed page of {} file(s).", objects.size());
    }

    // Add current results page to the end.
    for (final SwiftObject swiftObject : objects) {
        fileList.add(swiftObject.getName());
    }
    // Process will be repeated unless we have incomplete page.

} while (objects.size() >= LIST_PAGE_LIMIT);
```